# Why jobs running with set "only" keyword?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I tried to spice my gitlab gitflow with gitlab-cicd. My goal is to create a job which is running while a merge request and check if the source branch for this merge request is either a `hotfix/*` or `release/*` branch. A simple bash script is in charge for this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$1" =~ ^hotfix/* ]]; then
    echo "Begin Hotfix Merge"
    exit 0
else 
    echo "ERROR: Directory does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
```

where `$1` is the predefined variable `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME` as argument of the script.

My `.gitlab-ci.yaml` looks the following:

```yaml
image: ubuntu:latest

stages:
  - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH 

test1:
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Do a test here"
    - echo "For example run a test suite"
    - echo $PWD
    - ls -la .gitlab/

job1:
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  script:
    - echo "This job runs in merge request pipelines"
    - echo $PWD
    - ls -la .gitlab/workflow-scripts/
    - echo "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME"
    - bash ./.gitlab/workflow-scripts/check_sourcebranch.sh "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME" 
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - master
```

I am not shure if the `workflow:rules` distrubs anything. If I now start a merge request the pipeline runs without any issues inside the merge request, but if I aprove the request and the pipeline gets triggered again, both jobs are running.

Any Idea, why `job1` is triggered, even with the `only` rule?

EDIT: I removed the part with the unexpected error. This Error was a residual of a classic copy&pasta and was actually expected in this scenario.

Comment: [only and except are not being actively developed. rules is the preferred keyword to control when to add jobs to pipelines.](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#only--except)

Answer (score 1):

Fixed job for testing branch name on MR:

```yaml
stages:
  - tests
    
image: ubuntu:latest

test-mr-branch-name:
  stage: tests
  only:
    - merge_requests
  tags:
    - docker
    - linux
  script:
    - |
      if [[ ! "${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_NAME}" =~ ^(hotfix|release)\/.+$ ]]; then
        echo "ERROR: Wrong Merge!"
        exit 1
      fi
```

p.s. Operator between values of `only` tag is `or`. [Read me](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#specify-when-jobs-run-with-only-and-except).

p.s. You may set [multiline bash script in Gitlab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands).

Comment: Sorry for late response. Since you pointed to Operator between values `only` tag is `or`. Is it somehow possible to achieve it with an `and` operator? Your Example looks fine but is it also triggering on all Merge Request? Example Running a Merge from `Feature-1` to `Develop` might also fail, but shouldn't